# How to resolve generic interfaces using Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-mvc-5, inversion-of-control, autofac

Using Autofac as a DI container, I have run into a problem in implementation of a generic permission handler for checking if a User/Principal has access to a specific entity.

The Permission Services use the following generic interface:

```
public interface IClaimsPrincipalPermission<in TPrincipal, in TAction, in TResource> 
    where TPrincipal : AppUserPrincipal
    where TAction : BaseSecurity.Actions
    where TResource : BaseSecurity.Resources
{
    IdentityResult CheckAccess(SecurityAction secuirtyAction, TPrincipal principal, TAction action, TResource resource);
    IdentityResult CheckAccess(SecurityAction secuirtyAction, TPrincipal principal, TAction action, TResource resource, string id);
}
```

Where an example implementation would be:

```
internal class FruitClaimsPrincipalPermission
    : IClaimsPrincipalPermission<AppUserPrincipal, UpdateAction, FruitResource>

{
    private readonly IFruitRepository _fruitRepository;

    public FruitClaimsPrincipalPermission(IFruitRepository fruitRepository)
    {
        if (fruitRepository == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fruitRepository");
        _fruitRepository = fruitRepository;
    }

    #region Implementation of IClaimsPrincipalPermission<AppUserPrincipal, UpdateAction, FruitResource>
    public IdentityResult CheckAccess(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction secuirtyAction, AppUserPrincipal principal, CreateAction action, FruitResource resource) {
        if (principal == null || action == null || resource == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return IdentityResult.Failed(SecurityResouces.Requires_Authentication);

        if (!principal.IsSetupAdministrator)
            return IdentityResult.Failed(SecurityResouces.Requires_Setup_Admin_Role);

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }

    public IdentityResult CheckAccess(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction secuirtyAction, AppUserPrincipal principal, CreateAction action, FruitResource resource, string id) {
        if (principal == null || action == null || resource == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return IdentityResult.Failed(SecurityResouces.Requires_Authentication);

        if (!principal.IsSetupAdministrator)
            return IdentityResult.Failed(SecurityResouces.Requires_Setup_Admin_Role);

        var fruit = _fruitRepository.GetById(id);

        if (fruit.AccountId != principal.AccountId)
            return IdentityResult.Failed(SecurityResouces.Owner_Account_User_Mismatch);

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The web application is in MVC 5 and .Net 4.5. I have created a custom Authorize Attribute that would decorate any controller that requires authorization of access to a specific entity. **ResourceType** and **ActionType** are both Enums that represent the Resource and Action in the authorization request.

```
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly ResourceType[] _resources;
    private readonly ActionType _action;

    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(ActionType action, params ResourceType[] resources)
    {
        _resources = resources;
        _action = action;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var principal = new AppUserPrincipal(httpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        var action = ActionRepository.FindActions(_action);
        var resources = _resources.Select(ResourceRepository.FindResource).ToArray();
        return ClaimsAuthorization.CheckAccess(action, resources.First(), principal, "", out result);
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

}
```

**ClaimsAuthorization** is a sub class of ClaimsAuthorizationManager and implements a static CheckAccess method.

```
public class ClaimsAuthorization : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{

    public static bool CheckAccess(Actions action, Resources resource, AppUserPrincipal principal, string entityId, out IdentityResult result)
    {
        result = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPermissionExecutor>().CheckAccess(SecurityAction.Demand, principal, action, resource);
        return result.Succeeded;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to call the correct implementation of **IClaimsPrincipalPermission** from the static CheckAccess method in the ClaimsAuthorization class.

I wasn't able to figured out how to inject the correct instance of **IClaimsPrincipalPermission** to the ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute (research led me to believe that it is impossible) from the controller and it seemed like my only option was to resolve the dependency from within the ClaimsAthorization class. Therefore, I tried to resolve the dependency by using **DependencyResolver.Current.GetService** and creating a **PermissionExecutor** that implemented an **IPermissionExecutor**. For the sake of not extending this question any longer, I will not include those here. What is the correct approach to solving this problem?